# When does the determinant distribute over addition?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, linear-algebra, determinants, matrix-theory, block-matrices

1. When does $\det(A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)$ hold?
2. I actually wonder if there is an easy answer for when $Per(A+B)=Per(A)+Per(B)$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

let me assume $A$ is invertible, then you ask when
$$\det(1+X)=1+\det X,\;\;X=A^{-1}B $$
so if $X$ has eigenvalues $x_i$, $i=1,2,\ldots n$, you would need
$$\prod_{i}(1+x_i)=1+\prod_i x_i$$
basically you can take arbitrary values for $x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{n-1}$ and then the only requirement is that 
$$x_n=\frac{1-U}{U-V},\;\;U=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(1+x_i),\;\;V=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i$$

Comment: @Turbo, the given identity formula for $x_n$ is just a rearrangement of the desired identity, so it's necessary and sufficient.  There is certainly a formula involving only the entries—just write out the determinants in terms of the entries—but it seems unlikely to be very interesting ….

Comment: @Turbo, I'm no expert, but, since you are asking for equalities rather than, say, asymptotics of computing the determinant, I'm not sure how sparsity could help.  (After all, for a fixed $n$, it's just as valid to say that a given matrix has $\mathrm O(n)$ as $\mathrm O(1)$ non-zero entries per row.)

Comment: (Oops, I meant $\mathrm o(n)$.)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker does it work for matrices over rings with no zero divisors?

Comment: If you take the field of fractions, you can basically reduce the case of an integral domain to that of a field (you only have to check whether the expression for $x_n$ you get still lies in the ring).